# Mac 19,1 Sonoma startup manager displays HHD icon of a deleted Boot Camp partition...need to remove it

Tags: bootcamp, startup

I recently moved a Boot Camp partition to an external drive and erased the old Boot Camp partition on the iMac. I successfully added the newly unallocated APFS formatted space to the Mac HDD partition and all seems well. However, if I use the startup manager to boot to a new Boot Camp external drive, I notice there is still an HDD icon for the old internal Boot Camp drive displayed. I have reloaded the OS but the icon persists even though the internal drive Boot Camp partition no longer exists. How do I get rid of that icon being displayed as a choice in the startup manager?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different! My guess is that even though Bootcamp was removed, the bootloader is still in your EFI partition; I would try using [MountEFI](https://github.com/corpnewt/MountEFI) and deleting `/Volumes/EFI/Microsoft`. Just make sure not to delete the Apple directory!

Comment: Why download and use third party software? Can you not just use the command `sudo diskutil mount disk0s1`?